# Flex does not remove yyunput even with suitable flags

Tags: lex, flex-lexer

I'm Flexing a file with the

```
%option nounput
```

Option and using the command line

```
flex --nounput
```

And flex version 2.5.35.

However, the cpp output still contains the line

```
#define unput(c) yyunput( c, (yytext_ptr)  )
```

And this causes compilation problems with g++ since unput is not used.

Is there some way to fix this problem in a "clean" way? The two dirty ways are obvious:

1. Use unput in some useless way.
2. Remove the line automatically from the generated cpp file using some script.

Comment: I don't experience this problem. The version I am using is the same (flex 2.5.35). `%option nounput` does the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Good program but badly out of date documentation.

I found that version 2.6.4 accepts the nounput option and does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

(I tried to flag this question as "problem no longer reproducible" but the flag timed-out/aged away. [I'm answering it so that it does not remain an open unanswered question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

As mentioned by @akond:

> I don't experience this problem. The version I am using is the same (flex 2.5.35). `%option nounput` does the trick for me.

I also tried this on version 2.5.4 and can confirm there is no issue. The option `--nounput` is no longer recognised or [documented](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Index-of-Scanner-Options.html); however, the `%option nounput` [remains in the manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Scanner-Options.html).

The cpp output still does contain the line `#define unput(c) yyunput( c, yytext_ptr )` but this does not seem to generate any g++ errors for me. Are you using `-pedantic-errors` or some other similar option perhaps?